# How to make a listview fragment with image?

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I tried to put this code in other project but it doesn't work.

***ListView Activity Project***

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView fst;
    String[] placesname={"Place 1","Place 2","Place 3","Place 4","Place 5","Place 6"};
    String[] desc={"Desc 1","Desc 2","Desc 3","Desc 4","Desc 5","Desc 6"};
    Integer[] imgid={R.drawable.img1,R.drawable.img2,R.drawable.img3,R.drawable.img4,R.drawable.img5,R.drawable.img6};
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        fst= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        CustomListview customListview=new CustomListview(this,placesname,desc,imgid);
        fst.setAdapter(customListview);
        fst.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                if(position==0) {
                    Intent myintent = new Intent(view.getContext(),touristspot1.class);
                    startActivityForResult(myintent,0);
                }
                if(position==1) {
                    Intent myintent = new Intent(view.getContext(),touristspot2.class);
                    startActivityForResult(myintent,1);
                }
            }
        });

    }
}
```

**CustomListview**

```
public class CustomListview extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private String[] placesname;
    private String[] desc;
    private Integer[] imgid;
    private Activity context;
    public CustomListview(Activity context, String[] placesname, String[] desc, Integer[] imgid) {
        super(context, R.layout.listview_layout, placesname);

        this.context = context;
        this.placesname = placesname;
        this.desc = desc;
        this.imgid = imgid;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        View r=convertView;
            ViewHolder viewHolder=null;
            if (r==null)
            {

                LayoutInflater layoutInflater=context.getLayoutInflater();
                r=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_layout,null,true);
                viewHolder=new ViewHolder(r);
                r.setTag(viewHolder);
            }
            else {

                viewHolder= (ViewHolder) r.getTag();
            }

            viewHolder.ivw.setImageResource(imgid[position]);
            viewHolder.tb1.setText(placesname[position]);
            viewHolder.tb2.setText(desc[position]);
            return r;

    }
    class ViewHolder
    {
        TextView tb1;
        TextView tb2;
        ImageView ivw;
        ViewHolder(View v)
        {
            tb1=v.findViewById(R.id.tubbaname);
            tb2=v.findViewById(R.id.tubbadesciption);
            ivw=v.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        }
    }
}
```

***The codes I wrote above doesn't work when I put to the fragment. The codes I wrote below is another project where I put the codes mentioned above***

**Listview Fragment**

**PPTP**

```
public class pptp extends Fragment {


    public pptp() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_pptp, container, false);
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        String[] awayStrings = {
                "Top Wonders",
                "Top Tourist Destinations",
                "Cities to Visit",
                "Romantic Places",
                "Family Destinations",
                "Best Honeymoon Destinations",
                "Adventure Sports Destinations",
                "Amusement Parks",
                "Best Beaches",
                "Monuments",
                "Historical Places",
                "National Parks and wild life sanctuary",
                "Places to Visit",
                "Beautiful Caves",
                "Best Cathedrals",
                "EcoNature Tourism",
                "Top Museums",
                "Beautiful Lakes",
                "Most Beautiful Sandbars",
                "Popular Street foods",
                "General Information",
        };

        ListView lv = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView);

        ArrayAdapter<String> lva = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, awayStrings);
        lv.setAdapter(lva);

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {

                if(position == 0){
                    List1TW fragment = new List1TW();
                    FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
                    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                    transaction.commit();

                }
            }
        });
        return view;
    }

}
```

**ViewPageAdapter**

```
public class ViewPageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{

    ArrayList<Fragment> fragments = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> tabTitles = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addFragments (Fragment fragments,String tabTitles){
        this.fragments.add(fragments);
        this.tabTitles.add(tabTitles);
    }

    public ViewPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return fragments.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return fragments.size();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return tabTitles.get(position);
    }
}
```

***In Fragment what will I do to view image in listview?***

Comment: Show the code where you called the adapter in ‘Fragment’

Comment: I already wrote it. Its ViewPageAdapter

Comment: there is a difference in `FragmentPagerAdapter` and `ArrayAdapter<String>`

Comment: In FragmentPagerAdapter what should i do? Can you give me some codes to view image in listview fragment.

Comment: `pptp` is the fragment in which you want to show?

Comment: Yeah in pptp. Image with Text in fragment its so hard but when in comes to activity its easy. Help me how to make this listview with image.

Comment: Check the answer, It will help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is you are using simple `ArrayAdapter<String>` in fragment while in activity you are using custom `adapter` for images.

In your fragment replace

```
ArrayAdapter<String> lva = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, awayStrings);
    lv.setAdapter(lva);

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {

            if(position == 0){
                List1TW fragment = new List1TW();
                FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
                transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                transaction.commit();

            }
        }
    });
```

with

```
CustomListview customListview=new CustomListview(getActivity(),placesname,desc,imgid);
    lv.setAdapter(customListview);

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {

            if(position == 0){
                List1TW fragment = new List1TW();
                FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
                transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                transaction.commit();

            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: I will use the customlistview class?

Comment: yes you have to , as you are using simple `ArrayAdapter<String>` which is used to show a list of strings only , so when you are changing a layout i.e`custom layout` you have to define a `custom class` for it

Comment: What Activity will I use the main activity or the pptp fragment?

Comment: ofcourse your `pptp` fragment , where you want to show the list with images

Comment: I will add another this 

Integer[] imgid={R.drawable.img1,R.drawable.img2,R.drawable.img3,R.drawable.img4,R.drawable.img5,R.drawable.img6};

Comment: yes , if you want to show the images , as you asked in the question you want to display the images , so if you want to display the images at this `integer[] imgid`

Comment: Okay sir i will try. Thank you for helping me I appreciate it!

Comment: What's the issue?

Comment: If possible when the activity project the codes above i will apply in fragment?

Comment: I'm sorry didn't get what you said , can you explain

Comment: Sir one more. In this listview item onclick call another listview. What should I do to make the another listview with image.

Comment: thats also very simple, in xml file of layout of fragment , add another `listview` , then do the same process, you can apply the same `adapter` or if you have to change the `functionality  or layout` you can change the adapter

Comment: The codes? the string names it the same or i will change it.

Comment: if you want to show the exactly same data then , you can pass the same data , or if you want to change the data like different `Strings` then pass different `Array`

Comment: Sir It works Thank you for helping me again. I forgot to change the listview to another one.

Comment: @JoshuaDalisay that's great

Comment: Sir @Abdul Kawee one more question. It is possible if my mainactivity is tab layout I would like to add another activity to loading screen?

Comment: Yes its possible , you will have to change `<intent-filter>` for that activity ,  i.e change that new activity to `default and launcher` activity

Comment: Sir can you help me. When I try to click or touch the others spot in the fragment that not clickable it calls another fragment activity where I pointed.